# Chart.js How to make a sample math axis?

Tags: chart.js

I want to have x, y-axis like the following image.
[image]

It is really sample, but the x,y across on (0,0). and I want the negative part always shows whatever there is a point or now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a result close to your example image, but not exactly the same. You would probably need to [create a custom axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html) to align the tick labels to the zero line.

```js
let axisConfig = {
  drawBorder: false,
  gridLines: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    zeroLineWidth: 1
  },
  ticks: {
    max: 6,
    min: -6
  }
};
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "scatter",
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [axisConfig],
      yAxes: [axisConfig]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```